# Using generateStaticParams in next js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, generatestaticparams

Please tell me about using generateStaticParams in ext js 13 and using it with an interceptor and a parallel route

[image]

[image]

in these two pages I use this code

```
    export async function generateStaticParams(){
    const data = await getProducts({query:null})
    if(!data) return []
    return data.map((v)=>({
      slug:v.id.toString()
    }))
}
```

and when building a project, I get SSG for products/[id], but for the interceptor I get SSR, is that how it was intended or did I get something wrong?

[image]